# GET for AWS API Gateway to expose AWS DynamoDB database backend works for Test but not in Browser

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am following the youtube video :
**ep 1: How to use AWS API Gateway to expose AWS DynamoDB database backend.** I am using "selectdate" instead of "pageId" . When I test the api GET I get the desired output with path variable {selectdate} as November 3, 2018 and the corresponding attributes from the Dynamodb.

> /dgmvisit3/{selectdate} - GET - 
>   
>  Method Test Make a test call to your
>   method with the provided input
>
> Path {selectdate} 
>   November 3, 2018

However, when I test in the browser I do not get any output. The URL Changes.
 
https://   \< *api url*>   /prod/dgmvisit3/November 3, 2018
*changes to :*  
https:// *\< api url* > 
 /prod/dgmvisit3/November%203,%202018 
**How do I get the same output as Test ?**

Comment: did you publish your api? you are trying to add to path invalid character (space). Please look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) and parsing of your path key (date) is giving some error so please have a look at your logs of called API endpoints. Easier will be to give date as timestamp (number) instead of string representation

Comment: Thanks. I changed the selectdate format to 3-Nov-18 to get rid of the spaces and it worked.